# Partial Data refresh from prd to non prd

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to refresh PRD DB to Non PRD. However, I have space limitation on non prd since it is used by a lot of applications development, so I am thinking to only bring one year worth of data. Is there a way to do this? Please, keep in mind there are 100's of tables.

Comment: How big is the data, what are the constraints, how frequently do you need to run this data refresh, and how quickly does it need to be completed?

Comment: You will need to write your own query to extract the data from PRD and write to Non PRD. There isn't any build-in functionality in SQL Server that is able to do this

Comment: Did you forget to mention that [you are beginner](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b849897-1159-48aa-acd1-b9a4597f8f0c/i-am-a-beginner-and-i-am-looking-for-a-way-to-refresh-partial-data-1-year-data-to-lower?forum=sqldatabaseengine)? No, there is no easy way to do this nor is this a task for a beginner.